# matching multiple options to certain conditions

Tags: java, conditional-statements

What I am trying to achieve is to match multiple boolean options to matching conditions. So far this is my design. I am not happy with it. How does one write efficiently a multiple option matching to a condition? Or is having multiple options a major code smell?

```
class Condition 
{
    Boolean a; // Optional
    Boolean b; // Optional
    Boolean c; // Optional
    boolean d; // mandatory

    Condition(Boolean a, Boolean b, Boolean c, boolean d) 
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    public boolean matches(Boolean a, Boolean b, Boolean c, boolean b) 
    {
        return (a == null || this.a == a) 
               && (b == null || this.b == b)
               && (c == null || this.c == c)
               && (this.b == b);
    }   

    public static void main(String args[]) {
         Condition c1 = new Condition(true, true, null, true);
         Condition c2 = new Condition(null, null, false, false);
         Condition c3 = new Condition(false, true, null, true);
         Condition[] conditions = new Condition[]{c1,c2,c3};

         for (Condition con : conditions) {
             Boolean a = someTestLogic1(...);
             Boolean b = someTestLogic2(...);
             Boolean c = someTestLogic3(...);
             boolean d = someTestLogicMandatory(...);

             if (con.matches(a,b,c,d)) {
                 // found the matching condition
                 return con;
             }
         }             
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify - which part of this code are you unhappy with, in particular?

Comment: i suspect there is a more efficient (speed) and elegant way (less verbose) of achieving the same with lesser Constructor params, and also i don't like the looping of all conditions and breaking to find the first matching one

Comment: Are the method calls `someTestLogic1()`, etc... inside the `for` loop, is it right? The reason is, all those methods seem like zero-arg methods then how do they `return` diff. `boolean` values? I mean can they be outside the loop?

Comment: @javaguy i amended the code. the methods are just dummy methods to denote that its dynamic

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect there is a more efficient (speed) and elegant way (less
>   verbose) of achieving the same with lesser Constructor params, and
>   also I don't like the looping of all conditions and breaking to find
>   the first matching one.

There are obviously **few problems** with your current code like below:

(1) Passing `null` o satisfy the constructor call to create the instance, which is not good practice.

(2) Not using `equals()` method even though you are checking the equality of two objects of the same type.

So, the **answers** are below for the above problems:

(1) You can use [Builder pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html) to solve the first problem

(2) Obviously, you need to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods from `java.lang.Object` to match the equality of two objects.

---

The important point is that these two solutions might not be able to completely solve your verbosity i.e., avoiding the `if` checks or conditions (as they are part your core logic). But, these corrections will lead you in the right direction and make your code more structured (so less cluttered) and can easily be readable & maintained.